# Grouped bar plot column width uneven due to no data

Tags: r

I am trying to display a grouped bar plot for my dataset, however, due to some months have no data (no income), the column width is showing up as unequal and I was hoping to have the same column width regardless if some states have no income. Notice how the bar plot is grouped for January, something grouped like that across all months although other states have no income (I'd like to have them spaced out if some states do not have any income). Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(Checkouts, aes(fill=Checkouts$State, x=Checkouts$Month, y=Checkouts$Income)) + 
geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity")
```

[My Bar Plot](https://i.gyazo.com/b16ef6c064c9c844ff2d5ce2ff6f9f19.png)

[Checkouts table/data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCzDE.png)

Comment: please output your data as an r object with `dput(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that this can be done.

1. If you are using the latest version of ggplot2(from 2.2.1 I believe), there is a parameter called `preserve` in the function `position_dodge` which preserves the vertical position and adjust only the horizontal position. Here is the code for it.

**Code:**

```
import(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(Checkouts, aes(fill=Checkouts$State, x=Checkouts$Month, y=Checkouts$Income)) + 
geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single'))
```

2. Another way is to precompute and add dummy rows for each of the missing. using `table` is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for position_dodge2(preserve = "single")(https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(Checkouts, aes(fill = State, x = Month, y= Income)) + 
  geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

Also, you don't need to specify the columns to the data frame with $ in ggplot(). For example, Checkouts$State can be replaced with State.

Comment: This worked Travis, thank you so much, also appreciate your little tip with the data frames :)